# Symfony2: Flush XCache class cache on multiple instances on deployment

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, xcache

app/console cache:clear isn't clearing XCache (or APC) which can lead to major problems after redeployment when we're using AppCache in `app.php` (e.g. bootstrap.php.cache and all other generated `.cache.` files are cached).

app.php (pretty default)

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
$loader = new \Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\XcacheClassLoader('sf2dc4', $loader);
$loader->register(true);
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Our installation is distributed among 4 "application" servers so there's no way to reliably clear the cache on redeploys. What we would need is a way to tell all servers in our environment to flush their PHP/XCache. The APCBundle https://github.com/ornicar/ApcBundle seems to go that way but only works for APC.

A related problem is using the `doctrine:cache:clear-query` or `clear-metadata` commands. When we're using XCache as cache implementation for ORM metadata those commands actually don't flush anything at all even though they're writing "Clearing ALL Metadata cache entries
Successfully deleted cache entries." -> a look into XCache admin reveals that everything is still there. This is actually anticipated since Symfony commands run in the PHP CLI environment. Again, the APC Bundle would flush the caches correctly.

a) is it a "bug" that the commands say that everything has been flushed or are we missing something?
b) how could we reliably flush those caches on all our servers?
c) has anyone written a similar solution like the APCBundle and can come up with best practices how to handle those issues?
d) is it more feasible to restart each Apache after redeploy (no way but the hard way, our sysops would kill me for that idea)

Answer (score 2):

In case you have multiple instances you should use centralized cache storage (for example, Redis via [SncRedisBundle](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle) to keep sessions, doctrine meta and query cache). In this way you will have to clear doctrine metadata or query cache once as the last step in your deployment process.

There are several deployment strategies, but in all of them restarting Apache will do the trick. Though there are many alternatives regarding how you do it :) You can swap instances which has old code with instances which has new code (drop and warmup caches). Alternatively (if you are using load-balancers), you can add new instances into group and remove old instances.

On my experience restarting `php-fpm` (I don't use Apache for several years now) will clear APC in no time and it works very stable, also there is no downtime at all.

Feel free to ask me if there are still questions.

Comment: yeah, we've actually chosen to use Memcache as our result cache layer (it's there already and works fine). But to cache entity metadata and DQL>SQL transformations the xcache would totally suffice. The main problem is our "class" cache though: it'll keep old definitions unless we're flushing it. I don't think you can (should) cache opcode in Redis, do you :) ?

Comment: Then I would go for restarting php-fpm (or Apache in your case). Sure, no redis for opcode :)

Comment: tell that our admin who still believes you shouldn't restart your webserver :(